Common use of derogatory demonyms or country names in English
I was interested in the question of how proper names for countries and peoples that are unknown to the majority of native speakers, i.e. are not a linguistic norm, arise in modern English. In particular, I paid attention to the term "Transnistria", which is often used in English-language texts to refer to the Republic of Pridnestrovie (Eastern Europe, an unrecognized state). According to the available information, the word "Transnistria" is extremely offensive to Pridnestrovians; however, it is precisely this word that dominates the media space and texts that I can find today.
This is a truly amazing fact. I do not know of a single commonly used name for a country or people that would be directly offensive. If there were any before, they were long ago gotten rid of. This is apparently an exception. Therefore, the question arose: how or why did this term become widespread?
As I was able to find out, it's a purely colloquial word, since it is not fixed in any official document. Moreover, it arose precisely as a curse during a military conflict. Having studied the sources, I came to the conclusion that the word "Transnistria" spread in English-language texts in 2005-2010 , while the Republic of Pridnestrovie emerged in 1990. Previously, a whole range of names were in use, primarily "Dniester Republic". However, I could not find an explanation for this process.

Isn't this down to politics? The powers don't use the republic's name because they don't officially recognise the state.

Wikipedia gives a long explanation of the various names of the area. 'Curse' seems a bit strong - it's simply the Latin for 'over the Dniester' - but it's understandable that people don't like their region to be called by a name which isn't their own name for it.

Kate, the Wikipedia article has the same title. Can we expect any objectivity in this case? The Pridnestrovians' own sources say that this word means something like a death wish for their entire people.

KillingTime, of course, it is connected with politics. But how can politics influence language? The mechanism of this is interesting. I do not understand how a direct insult could come into use.

Is this question specifically about the case of Transnistria/Pridnestrovie, or is it about the general processes around the adoption of toponyms? The former may be more a question about history or politics than about the English language.

alphabet, I have not found any other similar cases, although it would be interesting. Perhaps this situation is unique. The history of this state and the term is known, I have no questions about it. The question is how an obviously offensive term could gain currency and begin to be used as a completely ordinary toponym/demonym. Of course, it is not part of the established vocabulary of the English language, but in specialized texts on this topic there is a clear trend.

The Republic of Pridnestrovie is not recognised, and although you say "common use" very few English speaking people have ever heard of it or Transnistria, nor of the local hatreds. There were related questions on SE Travel here with no answers, and here which talks about Transnistria. And there are overtly offensive names of countries, but this is due to ignorance not intent.

Weather Vane, yes, that's right. By "common use" I meant the ratio of usages of "Transnistria" and "Pridnestrovie".

Have you looked at the Wikipedia article? It seems to explain where the name came from. What additional information do you want?

Stuart, firstly, I have long since passed the age when reading and referring to Wikipedia is not a shame. Secondly, try re-reading my question again.

I vaguely remember having heard the name Transnistria mentioned in news bulletins. It doesn't take Wikipedia, though, to teach me that Trans- means the other side of (Transylvania = on the other side of the woods). I suppose the 'trans' prefix implies that the name is from someone else's point of view, but it can't literally mean a curse or death wish.

Kate, if I'm not mistaken, then any slur word can be etymologically reduced to a completely harmless basis. If I understood the Pridnestrovian sources correctly, then this word began to be used by Moldovan radicals and militants during the war in the early 1990s, who in this way declared their intentions to repeat the war crimes of the Second World War. However, it is interesting why this word ended up in the news bulletins.
